# Connecting a pi to an LCD monitor screen

Tags: video, screen

I want to build a raspberry pi photo frame. I understand that I can pick up a fairly cheap laptop LCD screen, but I'm confused about how to connect the raspberry pi and the screen.

I've seen LCD controller boards on ebay, which seem to be what I need, but I have no idea what type of LCD controller or type of LCD screen I need and how these interface with the pi.

Answer (score 1):

There is an instructables which might be helpful for you [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Laptop-Converted-to-2nd-Monitor/) providing you have a working laptop. However it seems like that is not the case, something like [this](http://stores.ebay.com/njytouch) is what you'd probably need. These Controller boards can convert the ribbon on laptop panels to more "universal" interfaces such as VGA, HDMI and DVI.